# Finding Distance From List Of Coordnates

Tags: excel, web, web-applications, excel-formula, distance

looking to see if someone can suggest a site or excel method to find the distance of multiple long,lat coordinates from a one point

example: I have a starting point and 7 other coordinates, is there a way to find how far away (in KM/MI) each point is from the starting point?

Starting loction : 33.17261,-117.14571

list of coordinates

32.75827,-117.17577

32.76079,-117.18589

32.76444,-117.20174

32.59815,-117.01685

32.66387,-117.05577

32.59811,-117.01681

32.66381,-117.05571

Comment: the answer will depend on if you want to consider curvature of the earth.  You can look up that formula with google though.  With your list of coordinates, are they in the same column?  ie stored as text with a , between them, or stored as numbers each in their own column?

Comment: they are stores in the same column, as displayed with "," in between. do not want to calculate curvature. thanks so much!

Comment: Crap, I was just going to treat this as X and Y point on a graph and use Sqrt(X^2+Y^2).  Unfortunately lat and lon are angles.  So you will be needing that curvature of the earth effect

Comment: This [website](http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/utility/NDSFutility.html) will do it for you one at a time.

Comment: [This website gives the formula for converting LAT and Lon into X and Y coordinate](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/626899/Converting-Latitude-And-Longitude-to-an-X-Y-Coordi)

Answer (score 0):

lets assume the column they are stored in is column A starting in row 2 (assuming you have a header row).  The first thing you are going to want to do is split them into their own columns so you can work with the numbers.  There are a couple of ways to do this.  The simplest is using the built in feature Text-to-Columns located on the Data ribbon.

[image: Text2Columns]

Have the whole column selected when you start the process and on the first page, select Delimited.

[image]

On the second step choose "," as a delimeter and then press finish.  You do not need the third step.

[image]

once that is done your data should now be sitting in two columns.

[image]

I will place the point you are referring to in C2 and D2,  you can use text to columns for this part too or just type it in.

So base on information on another site (assuming its correct), take the earth as a sphere with radius, 6371 km.  Place this value in E2.

Next convert your list into X and Y values using the following equations:

```
F2
=$E$2*COS(RADIANS($B2))*COS(RADIANS($A2))

G2
=$E$2*SIN(RADIANS($B2))*SIN(RADIANS($A2))
```

note that the degrees were converted to radians for use in excels trig functions

Repeat the process for you starting point coordinates and place the formulas in H2 and I2.

```
H2
=$E$2*COS(RADIANS($D2))*COS(RADIANS($C2))
I2
=$E$2*SIN(RADIANS($D2))*SIN(RADIANS($C2))
```

Finally in J2 use the following formula:

```
=SQRT((F2-$H$2)^2+(G2-$I$2)^2)
```

Copy the formulas in F2, G2, and J2 down as for as your source list goes.  The values in J represent the distance between the X Y points.  It does not the curvature of the earth though.  Apparently there are many different models to predict this.  You need one that works for your area if you want something more refined.

[image: POC]

Comment: I have splt them into their own columns, how do i compare the list to B2, C2 the long and lat columns for starting point

Comment: Added the final bit about comparison at the bottom.  take note of the web links in the comment section to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

For geodesic grade accuracy (fraction of a mm) you can use my Excel add-in available on GitHub:  https://github.com/tdjastrzebski/Vincenty-Excel, in particular `VincentyInvDistance()` function. The solution implements [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae),
Otherwise use [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) but it does not provide geodesic grade results.
The topic is not that trivial, see [Geodesics on an ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid) for more details.